# How to find d attribute value for reverse path in svg

Tags: svg

I am rendering an svg tree using d3.js. For a path connecting A to B I have the value for attribute d. From that how can I calculate d attribute for path connecting B to A

```
<path d="M535,73C33.75,73 33.75,-20 -467.5,-20" ></path>
```

Comment: Why would you want/need to do that? You could presumably just transform the path you have e.g. transform="scale(-1, -1)"

Comment: I need that to correct upside down textPath labels. I tried the method you said it shifts the path .  Currently I am calculating the attribute manually by interchanging the coordinates in the d attribute. [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/p9qfvoeb/)

Comment: If the path is shifted, transform it via translate(x, y)

Comment: Thanks for the solution :)

Comment: Here is a pen I found that does exactly what you want: https://codepen.io/enxaneta/pen/WWPYqQ
I don't fully understand it, but the code is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is now an npm module that handles this exact case quite well -
https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg-path-reverse